# MYSQL Sorting Using Order by

Tags: mysql, sql, mssql-jdbc

Hi I need help in sorting mysql query.

I have a column, where it contains the data like

R_5_TP(6),
R_5_TP(7),
R_5_TP(8),
R_6_TP(1),
R_6_TP(10),
R_6_TP(6),
R_50_TP(1),
R_7_TP(1),

I need to write a select query using order by and get the result as

R_5_TP(6),
R_5_TP(7),
R_5_TP(8),
R_6_TP(1),
R_6_TP(6),
R_6_TP(10),
R_7_TP(1),
R_50_TP(1),

Please help.Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? What errors do you get? SO isn't a code generator, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky.  I think you want:

```
order by substring_index(substring_index(col, '_', 2), '_', -1) + 0,  -- convert middle value to a number
         substring_index(col, '(', -1) + 0 -- convert parenthesized value to number
```

Comment: It is not able to solve my issue . It is sorting only the integer within in the brackets however the sorting order which expected  is different.